# JQ unable to parse JSON with embedded JSON on GIT BASH for WINDOWS

Tags: json, jq

I have a bash script (running on git bash for windows) that uses curl to get a json response from a server. The response contain a field that contain json data. The response looks like this:

```
[{
    "Status": "A",
    "JSON": "{\"field1\":\"value1\"}"
}, {
    "Status": "B",
    "JSON": "{\"field1\":\"value2\"}"
}]
```

here is the bash script I am trying to parse this string with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "parsing result in variable"
result='[{"Status":"A", "JSON":"{\"field1\":\"value1\"}"},{"Status":"B", "JSON":"{\"field1\":\"value2\"}"}]'
echo $result > json_in_json.json
result=$(echo "$result" | jq '[.[]."Status"]')
echo $result

echo "parsing result from file"
 jq '[.[]."Status"]' json_in_json.json
```

and here is what I see in terminal

```
parsing result in variable
[{"Status":"A", "JSON":"{\"field1\":\"value1\"}"},{"Status":"B", "JSON":"{\"field1\":\"value2\"}"}]
 ]B",
parsing result from file
[
  "A",
  "B"
]
```

Is there a way to make jq output the same result without going through a temp file?

Comment: The output you see is due to the output of `tee`, not anything to do with `jq`. Your script never touches the embedded JSON. `echo "$result" > json_in_json.json`  would have been sufficient.

Comment: TarekZ - What version of bash are you using?  On what platform?  I have no problem using your program with bash 3 or bash 4 on MacOS.

Comment: I am testing on git bash for windows. Bash version 4.4.12

Answer (score 1):

`jq` provides a `fromjson` function to parse embedded JSON. For example,

```
$ jq '.[].JSON | fromjson | .field1' tmp.json
"value1"
"value2"
```

Update:

The problem is not `jq`, but the fact that `tee` writes its input to standard output as well as to any files named as arguments. Redirect to `/dev/null`

```
echo "$result" | tee json_in_json.json > /dev/null
```

or don't use `tee` in the first place.

```
echo "$result" > json_in_json.json
```

Comment: I don't have a problem parsing that json from a file. But I am trying not to use a tmperory file and use the result stored in the variable. In addition, I don't care about the JSON part, what I care about is the Status field. The JSON field is just interfeering with the jq select.

Comment: Then see my comment; the issue has nothing to do with `jq`, but the fact that `tee` is dumping the full JSON to standard output before you display `jq'` result.

Comment: Also, in that case your question title is *entirely* misleading.

Comment: I put the tee in there to show that it is the same json stored in the variable result and the file. The tee can be removed if you copy the content of the string into a file. It will yield the same result. And like I said at the end of my post, I want to get the ["A","B"] result that I get when using the file, instead of the ]B, that i get when I try to parse the variable.

Comment: I see what you meant about the tee. I changed the script but the result is still the same. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Something else is going on that isn't visible in this question. You *should* be getting the exact same result, whether you use `echo "..." | jq '...'` or `jq '...' < some.json`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189547/discussion-between-tarekz-and-chepner).

Answer (score 0):

I had filed a bug with jq about this, but closed it since it wasn't reproducible on ubuntu or macos. Nico Williams explained what is happening here:

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1855